# Sibboleth with webapplication

Tags: java, servlets, saml

Shibboleth Login Issue For Web Application

I have a web application with database for login authentication.
Now I want to access third party site which is SAML compatible. To access them I installed shibboleth IDP now how do I configure the login? 
will my application be the login provider or Shibboleth will be the login provider. And how to configure the login?

Answer (score 0):

Shibboleth is a framework including a complete Web Application for login. (It has been achieved using Spring WebFlow).

If you use Shibboleth you don't need to create an other WebApp. Instead, you should customize the standard Shibboleth IDP webApp.

You should configure files in shibboleth-installation-folder like "conf", "credentials", "edit-webapp", etc.

I don't know which version of Shibboleth you are using, but you should read some documentation before to use Shibboleth, is not so simple. [Documentation for version IDP3.0](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Initialization+and+Configuration)